# How to put two pictureboxes into an array of pictureboxes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, picturebox

I'm writing a program with visual basic(in windows form application mode) and I have two pictureBoxes in this program,I want them to be an array,like `p[0]` and `p[1]`, is it possible in visual basic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an array of anything you want, including an array of PictureBoxes...
Haven't used VB.Net for ages, but if I remember the syntax correctly:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

....

Dim arr As System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox() = New PictureBox(2) {}
arr(0) = New PictureBox()
arr(1) = New PictureBox()
```

Comment: I've added the pictureboxes from toolbox to the windows form applicatio, Is there any solution to make them an array? like changing their names or something ?

Comment: @Navid777, You didn't state you want this done from the toolbox... Anyways - Unfortunately, I'm afraid if you use the designer you can't "group" a set of controls into an array...